# Can I have single line sized QTextEdit with simple html?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtextedit

I need to display simple status row with text which will contain following styles:

- color
- bold
- italic

`QTextEdit` can render simple HTML. But it also forcibly expands over multiple lines:

[image: image description]

Red background was added to emphasize the dimensions of the `QTextEdit`. Desired size is the size of one text line. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if you've simply used a `QLabel`, you'd not need to do anything special: it supports rich text format, and only takes as much space as necessary:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&w};
   QLineEdit edit;
   QLabel message{"Foo <font color=\"red\">Bar!</font>"};
   message.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
   message.setWordWrap(true);
   message.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
   layout.addWidget(&edit);
   layout.addWidget(&message);
   layout.addStretch();
   QObject::connect(&edit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &message, &QLabel::setText);
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

If you insist to use a `QTextEdit`: It contains a `QTextDocument`, laid out by its `documentLayout()`. The layout emits a signal each time its size changes. You can act on that signal to change the height of the widget to accommodate the size of the document. Take into account the structure of a `QTextEdit`: it is a `QAbstractScrollArea` and the contents are shown in the `viewport()` widget. The goal is for the `viewport()` to be large enough to fit the text document. The widget itself may be bigger, depending on the active style or style sheet.

Below is an example of how you might implement this. The contents of the line edit are propagated to the read-only `message` `QTextEdit`, so that you can note how the widget size is updated in the real time as the text gets too long to fit in one line. This automatically takes care of updating the size when you change the width of the widget, as the document size changes as well due to height-for-width trade-off.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/textedit-height-37945130
#include <QtWidgets>

void updateSize(QTextEdit * edit) {
   auto textHeight = edit->document()->documentLayout()->documentSize().height();
   edit->setFixedHeight(textHeight + edit->height() - edit->viewport()->height());
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&w};
   QLineEdit edit;
   QTextEdit message;
   message.setReadOnly(true);
   message.setText("Foo Bar!");
   layout.addWidget(&edit);
   layout.addWidget(&message);
   layout.addStretch();
   QObject::connect(&edit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &message, &QTextEdit::setPlainText);
   QObject::connect(message.document()->documentLayout(),
                    &QAbstractTextDocumentLayout::documentSizeChanged,
                    &message, [&]{ updateSize(&message); });
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use curly braces in constructors?

Comment: @TomášZato Why not? Construction and function/method calls are really two different animals, with shared overloaded syntax used for both in C++98. I'm thankful that the uniform initialization in C++11 finally disambiguates them.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe simple solution is to use `setFixedHeight` method of `QWidget` class (Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight)

```
yourTextEdit->setFixedHeight(/*Height for one text line*/);
```

Comment: But how do I know pixel height of one line?

Comment: Of course, you can use QFontMetrics. @IAmInPLS is right. It is the best way, i think. The other way - determine needed height practically, when you start you application. But this may be useful if you have only one QFont and styles for you QTextEdit. One more way - maybe use QLabel.

Comment: @IAmInPLS `QLabel` renders HTML? Ah, well I didn'[t know that. The sole reason for using `QTextEdit` instead of `QLabel` was to get HTML rendered...

Comment: @TomášZato I may be wrong since I heard in many places that `QLabel` was not a good fit for rendering HTML but a code like `QLabel *labelHTML = new QLabel("<strong>Hello</strong> " "<font color=red>World!");` works for me so I don't know what to believe anymore

Comment: I just tried to use QLabel and it worked quite well. I guess it's not good for big HTML documents, but I just need one line of text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the size of a text line, use [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html):

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
QFontMetrics metrics(textEdit->font());
int lineHeight = metrics.lineSpacing();
textEdit->setFixedHeight(lineHeight);
```

You may add one or two pixels to `lineHeight` if it is not enough.

Comment: Guessing at widget size by saying "you may add one or two pixels" is just wrong :(

Comment: This code is enough, it is just if the final visual rendering is not convenient for the OP

Comment: You're assuming a whole lot here. It's not enough. A `QTextEdit` renders a `QTextDocument`, using a certain layout. The `QTextEdit::font` doesn't have anything to do with the font or fonts used to display the text. And so on. You're trying to reinvent the wheel, wrongly. You can't assume that a rich text layout will render in a height given by the underlying widget's font.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent anything, just trying to do something in a simple way... I understand now it's not the right way (which is the way you showed in your answer), but I needed it for a basic example and this is what was working for me.

Comment: If anyone else comes here looking for the size of QTextEdit to be of single line, don't do this please. Instead just create a temporary `QLineEdit` with your font and use its `sizeHint()` method to get the correct height.

Answer (score 2):

You can create and initialize your textbox like so:

```
QTextEdit* te = new QTextEdit ("0");
te->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
te->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
te->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
te->setFixedHeight(50);
```

The critical property is `setLineWrapMode`, which I have set to `NoWrap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QLineEdit`. I'm not sure maybe it is recently added.

Comment: Are you sure it supports HTML?